# JSON Serialization DateOnly API, 'Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.'

Tags: c#, json, crud, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I have an application which is getting some data from a database and making some CRUD operations on them. I'm trying to make a HttpPut with a DateOnly type.

So I have a DateOnly Converter that I call in the Program.cs.

```
  public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
    {
        private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

        public override DateOnly Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return DateOnly.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
```

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(
    options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
    }
);
```

And I have the Model and Dto.

```
  public class CelestialObjectEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public double EquatorialDiameter { get; set; }
        public int SurfaceTemperature { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
        public DateOnly DiscoveryDate { get; set; }
        public int DiscoverySourceId { get; set; }
        public DiscoverySources DiscoverySource { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CelestialObjectDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public double EquatorialDiameter { get; set; }
        public int SurfaceTemperature { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
        public DateOnly DiscoveryDate { get; set; }
        public DiscoverySources DiscoverySource { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a Service class where i use Automapper and a Controller class where I do the HttPost.

```
public CelestialObjectDto AddCelestialObject(CelestialObjectForCreatingDto celestialObject)
        {

            var celestialNew = _mapper.Map<CelestialObjectEntity>(celestialObject);

            celestialObjectRepository.AddCelestialObject(celestialNew);

            var createdCelestialObject = _mapper.Map<CelestialObjectDto>(celestialNew);

            return createdCelestialObject;
        }
```

```
[HttpPost("add/{id}")]
        public IActionResult AddCelestialObject(CelestialObjectForCreatingDto? discovery)
        {
            CelestialObjectDto celestialObject;
            try
            {
                celestialObject =  celestialObjectService.AddCelestialObject(discovery);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }

            return Json(celestialObject);
        }
```

The problem is that when I try to make a HttpPut or HttpPost I have the next error in the DateOnlyConverter:

**'Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.'**

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the JSON you are trying to deserialize when the exception *`Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.'`* is thrown?  From the description it sounds like the JSON token isn't a string like `"2022-12-12"`, it's some sort of JSON object like `{"Year" : 2022, ...}`.